# Run Pgadmin 4 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, postgresql

Installed pgadmin4 using this tutorial https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/ with the difference I just downloaded their https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub and put it as:

```
file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages_pgadmin_org.asc
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages_pgadmin_org.asc: PGP public key block Public-Key (old)
```

apt source:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d>cat pgadmin4.list 
deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy pgadmin4 main
```

Installed only desktop:

```
apt install pgadmin4-desktop
```

So the problem is it doesn't start:

```
/usr/pgadmin4/bin>./pgadmin4 
[0618/131932.731277:ERROR:zip_reader.cc(153)] Cannot open ZIP from file handle 3
[0618/131932.731466:ERROR:zip.cc(202)] Cannot open ZIP from file handle 3
Opening in existing browser session.
```

Comment: Same problem, reinstall didn't help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I noticed that there are two postgresql services running, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I game up on the desktop version and simply followed these instructions for the web version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992446/installing-pgadmin4-web-on-ubuntu-desktop-22-04

Comment: I installed 6.11 and the problem is fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known issue with pgadmin4 6.10 on Ubuntu 20.04 (and Debian 11 Bullseye in my case): https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/7442?issue_count=380&issue_position=38&next_issue_id=7438&prev_issue_id=7444 (login required).

Downgrade to 6.9 works for me and the initial reporter:

```
sudo apt -y remove pgadmin4
sudo apt -y autoremove pgadmin4*
sudo apt -y install  pgadmin4-desktop*=6.9 pgadmin4-server*=6.9
```

Comment: Also on fedora   
https://superuser.com/questions/1728081/cannot-launch-postgresqls-pgadmin4-on-fedora36

Comment: Thank you, it works, can we assure that this package will not be upgraded to 6.10? I mean using apt upgrade

Comment: Use `apt-mark hold pgadmin4-desktop pgadmin4-server` to hold their versions

Answer (score 1):

It's 2022, In My Case, My Ubuntu 22.04 is installing Python3.10 by default, but PGAdmin requires to use python3.8 instead. So I need to install 3.8 and then pointed the PGAdmin python to use python3.8.

`ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3`

hope it help

Comment: Your answer refers to Ubuntu Core as that is the only version that would simply be called 22.

Comment: @David , Thank you for correction, I'm using 22.04

Answer (score 1):

### In March 2023 on Ubuntu 22.04 with pgadmin4:

Apparently pgadmin4 expects python3.8 to be installed (see `ls -lah /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3`), which my system didn't have after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.

Installing python3.8 solved it:

```bash
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.8
python3.8 --version
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/1430123/48214 and https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/ were helpful for me.

Comment: Warning: Just because you're installing a new Python version doesn't mean you can uninstall other versions. NEVER uninstall Python from Ubuntu. Look at the countless horror stories online of people online who did this. It wrecked everything, and I needed to reinstall Ubuntu (after wasting _days_ trying to solve it without a complete reinstall).